# Warning messages related to superscript and mathshift in my latex file with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, warnings

I am writing a manuscript. I am trying to use hyperref.

I have two warning messages.

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `math shift' on input line 215.
```

and

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `superscript' on input line 215.
```

Which are a result of this line

```
\subsubsection{Nextel $^{TM} 312$}
```

I am currently compiling with Overleaf. How can I remove the error messages?

Comment: these are warnings not errors. They mean that you loose some math in the bookmarks. You can use \texorpdfstring to define some replacement.

Answer (score 1):

If you use math mode here you need to specify a text form for the pdf bookmarks, or you can use a form that works in both. I kept the white space as you had it, although I would have expected no space before  `™` and a space after.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Nextel \texorpdfstring{$^{TM} 312$}{™ 312}}
abc


\subsubsection{Nextel ™312}
abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks. That works a treat.